# What is the browser equivalent of autocomplete="off" for all input fields?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

We have an existing web application with hundreds of input fields through different applications that has been installed at several sites. At this most recent site, however, we have started having an issue with the back button automatically filling in input fields. This is an issue because the only time we allow the back button is if an error occurred in processing. So the flow is as follows:

1) ask user to scan a barcode

2) an error occurs on the back-end and it directs them to an error page with only a back button

3) the user hits back and is directed to the input page, input form is now filled with the previously inputted data.

I know this is some form of caching or browser issue because when I hit the web app from my personal pc, it doesn't do it. But when they use their android scanning devices and if we load it up on the application server, it does.

I have fixed this on a couple of pages with `autocomplete="off"` on the input fields, but it just isn't feasible for us to change this on each of hundreds of input fields if we can avoid it. I'm looking for some browser or windows function to turn off to disable this.

I have tried turning off all of the chrome autocomplete fields, and I have tried disabling the cache in dev tools with no luck. Is there another way to disable this without using that `autocomplete` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If inputs are inside form you can put it on form.

If not you've only one option to use a global script to add attribute on each input something like below but it'll put it on every input and I'm not sure if it'll have any side effects for your case:

`field.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "new-password" );`

Hope it helps.